# How to show link between a java class which gets JSON data from PHP script

Tags: uml, diagrams, class-diagram

I am trying to show the relationship that a java class has with a PHP script. The PHP script gets data from a database and then converts it into JSON format. This is then read by the java file.

In my UML diagram, is there a way to show the relationship between the database and the java class? Should I even bother with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends if this relationship makes sense in the context of your diagram and what the focus is.

It feels to me as if this PHP script acts as a service of some kind (provides access to data the java class cannot get directly from the database) so I would probably model the script as a [component](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_%28UML%29) on the diagram. A component provides an abstraction of where the data comes from as the java class does not really care about this, it simply sees the script as a provider of a certain kind of data.